# HTTP proxy stripping authorization header requires cooke

Tags: c#, cookies, proxy, dotnet-httpclient

I'm trying to use a REST API from behind a web proxy in my C# application that requires basic authentication.

I've tested my credentials using the Postman chrome app, and verified that they work. However, when I run my C# application, I receive a 401 Unauthorized response.

After looking at some traces of the Postman requests and using http://httpbin.org with my C# application, what I think is happening is that the web proxy that I'm behind is not forwarding the Authorization header, because my request is missing a cookie that (I think) is being set by smarter web clients (e.g., Postman, which is built on top of Chrome). I can see in the Postman network trace that it's sending a cookie that looks like it's related to the proxy.

I don't know how to replication this in my C# application as I'm using fairly high-level APIs. Any help would be appreciated:

#### Update:

I was able to get it to work by copying the cookie that I saw in the trace and adding it to my request (by inserting it into the `CookieStore`). However, I'm not sure how I can make this automatic. Chrome must be getting this cookie value somehow and storing it. Is there a way that I can get my application to do the same?

```cs
WebRequest.DefaultWebProxy.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultNetworkCredentials;

HttpClientHandler handler = new HttpClientHandler()
{
    UseCookies = true,
    CookieContainer = new System.Net.CookieContainer()
};
HttpClient client = new HttpClient(handler);

var byteArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(USER + ":" + PASS);
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization =
            new System.Net.Http.Headers.AuthenticationHeaderValue("Basic",
Convert.ToBase64String(byteArray));

var content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(new Dictionary<string, string> {
            { "field1", "value1" },
            { "field2", "value2" }
});

Console.WriteLine("Sending request");

var response = await client.PostAsync(HTTP_URL, content);
var responseString = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

Console.WriteLine("Server response (" + response.StatusCode + "):\n" + responseString);
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you've correctly "enabled" cookies, so any you get back in the response should be sent automatically with each subsequent request, **provided you're reusing the same `HttpClient` instance for each of those requests**.

As a side note, if you don't mind a small library dependency, [Flurl](http://tmenier.github.io/Flurl/) [disclaimer: I'm the author] would simplify your code substantially:

```
var client = new FlurlClient().EnableCookies();

var response = await HTTP_URL
    .WithClient(client)
    .WithBasicAuth(USER, PASS)
    .PostUrlEncodedAsync(new {
        field1 = "value1",
        field2 = "value2",
    });
```